# How to convert a StringBuilder of integers into an array of ints?

Tags: java

So for an assignment I had to write a method that would take two arrays and interleave them. I chose to convert those arrays to strings, take substrings of each string and add them to a stringbuilder. Now I should have a stringbuilder full of integers from both arrays, but the method the teacher wants us to create must return an array of ints. How can I convert this stringbuilder to an array of ints?

Here's my code so far:

```
public static int[] interleaveArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2, int stride, int maxElements){

    if (stride <= 0){
        return null;
    }
    if (maxElements <= 0){
        return null;
    }

    String arrayA = array1.toString();
    String arrayB = array2.toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(array1.length + array2.length);

    boolean done = false;
    boolean end = false;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (done = false){//create a substring of the first array & append to stringbuilder
        String newArray1 = arrayA.substring(i, i + (stride - 1));
        sb.append(newArray1);
        if (i > arrayA.length()){
            done = true;
        }
        while (end = false){//create a substring of the second array & append to stringbuilder
            String newArray2 = arrayB.substring(j, (j + stride - 1));
            sb.append(newArray2);
            if (j > arrayB.length()){
                end = true;
            }
        }
        if (sb.length() >= maxElements){
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

(side note:

**stride** is the amount of integers that should be taken at a time from each array. [e.g. if you have a stride of 2 and the arrays **{1, 3, 7, 2}** and *{5, 2, 9, 6}*, the array returned should be {**1, 3,** *5, 2,* **7, 2,** *9, 6*}]

**maxElements** is the maximum number of integers allowed in the returned array)

Comment: You *definitely* don't want to call `array1.toString()`. You might mean `Arrays.toString(array1)`. (Similarly for `array2.toString()`)

Comment: You also almost certainly don't mean `done = false` (which sets `done` to `false`, meaning the loop never breaks), but rather `done == false`, or `!done`. (Similarly for `end = false`).

Comment: Why do you think you need to use strings at all? This dramatically complicates a simple problem.

Comment: I don't think your teacher wanted a solution using StringBuilder (or at least I hope so). You can solve the problem much easier by creating a new array and adding all elements in correct order to the new array.

Comment: Rethink your entire approach. If you have a collection of integers and need to iterate them, you don't output them, parse the string into individual elements, add them to a new collection and then turn it back into integers. Instead, you iterate them properly and just add these to the new collection. Done.

Comment: You definitely do not want to convert the arrays to Strings. Consider the int array {1, 23, 22345, 2, 77}. Your algorithm using stride depends on each integer being a single digit.

Comment: Andy Turner, how would you suggest I go about the problem? It seems like it would be easiest to simply create another array and add the correct values in the proper order, but I have no idea how to do that.